# Delphi XE5: Calling EWS with Interface created by WDSL-Import without impersonation

Tags: delphi, impersonation, exchangewebservices

I'm currently working on sync of calendar appointments from our application to an Exchange Server 2007 SP1 on Win Server 2008. It should handle deleting and adding appointments for multiple user-accounts. The interface is created with the WDSL-Import component of Delphi XE5. It generates a type 'ExchangeServicePortType' used like this:

```
var
  ws: ExchangeServicePortType;
  exCreate: CreateItem;
  exItemResp: CreateItemResponse;
  exImper: ExchangeImpersonation;
  secContext: SerializedSecurityContext;
  exMailboxCult: MailboxCulture;
  exReqServerVersion: RequestServerVersion;
  exServerVersion: ServerVersionInfo;
....
ws := GetExchangeServicePortType(false);
...
exImper.ConnectingSID.SID := <useraccount>; 
...
ws.CreateItem(exCreate, exImper, secContext, exMailboxCult, exReqServerVersion,  
    exCreateItemResponse, exServerVersion);
```

The problem:
It only works fine with 'impersonation' in the following situation:

- A 'syncuser' is running the sync-programm on the client.
- The 'syncuser' account on the server has the special rights ms-Exch-EPI-Impersonation,ms-Exch-EPI-May-Impersonate for all user-accounts.
- calling cmdlet 'Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "user-account" -User  -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All' for all  on the server.
- EWS authentication = windows-authentication

Question: Is there any possibility to call EWS without 'impersonation' in Delphi XE and how does it works?

In the managed API one could call:

```
ExchangeServiceBinding ws = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
ws.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
```

Any help/idea/explanation/suggestion greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks at David Heffernan. 
I have tried the suggested approach using a C#-dll (Visual Studio 2010) with the .DllExport extension from R. Giesecke and the EWS managed api 1.2. The code looks like:

```
EWSTerminSync.cs
...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
...

public class  EWSSync
{      
   public static ExchangeService service;

    private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
       object sender,
       System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
       System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
       System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        ...
    }   

   [DllExport]
    public static int InitEWS()
    {           
       (0)ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;               

      (1) service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
       service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("name", "pwd", "domain");
       service.Url = new Uri("https://myServer/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
       ...
    }   
    [DllExport]
    public static int DoSomething()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

The C#-dll is loaded in a Delphi7 application like this:

```
type
TCreateInstance = function(): integer; stdcall;

FDLLHandle: THandle;
...
procedure Execute()
var
    res: integer;
begin
FDLLHandle := LoadLibrary(pansichar('EWSTerminSync.dll'));
if FDLLHandle >= 32 then
begin
    @FCreateInstance := GetProcAddress(FDLLHandle, 'InitEWS');

    res := FCreateInstance;
    ...
end;
...
end;
```

If it is executed as a delphi application, all works fine. I can create-/delete appointments and calendars and other stuff.
But I have to use it in a delphi application running as a windows service. The same code produces error "EXCEPTION: EExternalException / Externe Exception E0434352". 
running line (1) in function InitEWS(). Without calling any ews managed api functions, just doing some string operations in function InitEWS(), everything works correctly in the service too.
The application and the service are running under the same  user credentials.

Is there any restriction using the ews managed api in a windows-service?
What settings must be performed in order to call an ews managed api function in a service?

Comment: Why don't you write a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly. Export the functionality you need using `__declspec(dllexport)`. Or use a C# assembly and publish a COM interface. Then you can expose the managed interface to your Delphi code.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that only in the managed API specifying Username, Password, and Domain is possible or is there something wrong with the WSDL import from Delphi XE?

Comment: The managed code is WSDL also right? WSDL is notoriously rubbish in Delphi. Probably is just duff WSDL.

Comment: @user2964249 it looks like the second half of your question text is both an answer your original question and a new question. Can you make it such - i.e. write an answer yourself (you can mark it as correct after 48 hours), and write a new question (reference this one if necessary)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ews without the impersonation just the problem is what Delphi adds an xml node even for the nil parameter (regardless of soDontSendEmptyNodes option). I cannot find a better way to eliminate this than to create a new TOPToSoapDomConvert class which simply skips nil parameters.

```
unit SoapHelpers;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Soap.IntfInfo, Soap.InvokeRegistry, Soap.OPToSOAPDomConv;

type

  TOPToSoapDomConvert2 = class(TOPToSoapDomConvert)
  public
    function InvContextToMsg(const IntfMD: TIntfMetaData;
                              MethNum: Integer;
                              Con: TInvContext;
                              Headers: THeaderList): TStream; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.TypInfo;

type
  TInvContextTmp = class(TInvContext)
  public
    procedure CopyPointers(Cont: TInvContext);
    procedure RemovePointer(Index: Integer);
  end;

const
  IS_OUT  = $0200;

{ TOPToSoapDomConvert2 }

// Skip null parameters they are always being sent regardless of sendemptynodes settings
function TOPToSoapDomConvert2.InvContextToMsg(const IntfMD: TIntfMetaData;
  MethNum: Integer; Con: TInvContext; Headers: THeaderList): TStream;
var
  MethMD: TIntfMethEntry;
  Params, ParamsSave: TIntfParamEntryArray;
  Con2: TInvContextTmp;
  P: Pointer;
  I, K, XmlOptions, ParamCountSave, ParamCount: Integer;
  ExtParamName, ParamNamespace: string;
begin
  MethMD := IntfMD.MDA[MethNum];

  ParamsSave := MethMD.Params;
  ParamCountSave := MethMD.ParamCount;
  ParamCount := MethMD.ParamCount;

  SetLength(Params, Length(MethMD.Params));
  for I := Low(Params) to High(Params) do
    Params[I] := MethMD.Params[I];

  Con2 := TInvContextTmp.Create;
  Con2.CopyPointers(Con);

  for I := High(Params) downto Low(Params) do
  begin
    InvRegistry.GetParamInfo(IntfMD.Info, MethMD.Name, Params[I].Name,
                             ExtParamName, ParamNamespace, XMLOptions);

    if not ((pfOut in Params[I].Flags) or ((XMLOptions and IS_OUT) = IS_OUT)) then
    begin
      P := Con.GetParamPointer(I);
      if (Params[I].Info <> nil) and (Params[I].Info.Kind = tkClass) and (Pointer(P^) = nil) then
      begin
        for K := I + 1 to High(Params) do
          Params[K-1] := Params[K];
        SetLength(Params, Length(Params)-1);

        Dec(ParamCount);
        Con2.RemovePointer(I);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if Length(MethMD.Params) <> Length(Params) then
  begin
    MethMD.ParamCount := ParamCount;
    MethMD.Params := Params;
    IntfMD.MDA[MethNum] := MethMD;
  end;

  try
    Result := inherited InvContextToMsg(IntfMD, MethNum, Con2, Headers);
  finally
    if Length(MethMD.Params) <> Length(ParamsSave) then
    begin
      MethMD.ParamCount := ParamCountSave;
      MethMD.Params := ParamsSave;
      IntfMD.MDA[MethNum] := MethMD;
    end;
    Con2.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TInvContextTmp }

procedure TInvContextTmp.CopyPointers(Cont: TInvContext);
var
  k: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(DataP, Length(TInvContextTmp(Cont).DataP));
  for k := Low(TInvContextTmp(Cont).DataP) to High(TInvContextTmp(Cont).DataP) do
    DataP[k] := TInvContextTmp(Cont).DataP[k];
end;

procedure TInvContextTmp.RemovePointer(Index: Integer);
var
  k: Integer;
begin
  for k := Index+1 to High(DataP) do
    DataP[k-1] := DataP[k];
end;

end.
```

When, you can use it like this:

```
...
    lRIO := THTTPRio.Create(nil);

    lRIO.Converter := TOPToSoapDomConvert2.Create(lRIO);
    lRIO.Converter.WSDLView := nil;
...
```